# Java custom classes

Tags: java, class, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Watch{

// instance variables for the class watch
private String name;    
private long serial_no;
private String desc;
private String color;
private double price;
private double weight;
private int hour;
private int min;
private int sec;

ArrayList<Watch> watchStore = new ArrayList<Watch>();

public void addWatch(String nme, long s_r, String ds, String cl, double pr, double wg){
    watchStore.add(new Watch(nme, s_r, ds, cl, pr, wg));
}

public String disWatch(){
    return watchStore.get(watchStore) + "";
}
```

In my `addWatch` method I am creating a `new Watch` to add to an ArrayList, inside of the `Watch` class. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it would be better to have two classes: `Store` and `Watch`, where the class `Store` contains a list like `ArrayList<Watch> watches;`.

Class `Store`:

```
public class Store {
   private ArrayList<Watch> watches;

   public Store() {
      watches = new ArrayList<>();

      // Add first watch
      watches.add(new Watch(...));
   }
}
```

And the class `Watch`:

```
public class Watch {
   private String name;    
   private long serial_no;
   private String desc;
   private String color;
   private double price;
   private double weight;
   private int hour;
   private int min;
   private int sec;

   public Watch(...) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Let me know, if you have any trouble. I will then update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not? But make more a container class to store watches (`WatchStore`).

Comment: ok but how would that be...??? because I tried what I did in the addWatch method with the disWatch method but no success...

Comment: Why do you want to store watches inside a watch class, make a WatchStore class  and store watches inside that class.